# Uploading a file to AWS S3 storage doesn't work

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have three PHP files and one text file.
I tried to follow the tutorial in youtube (Amazon S3 with PHP: Uploading Files (1/6 - 4/6)). It doesn't work properly as discussed in the tutorials.

The folder and file structures are

```
--var/www/html/tutorials/s3->upload.php
--var/www/html/tutorials/s3->files->uploadme.txt
--var/www/html/tutorials/s3->app->config.php, start.php
```

Basically is I am trying to upload the  uploadme.txt to AWS S3 storage.
Three files are

config.php

```
 return [
    's3' => [
       'key' => '-- key --',
       'secret' => '-- secret --',
       'bucket' => '-- bucket --'
     ]
 ];

?>
```

start.php

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$config = require('config.php');

//S3
$s3 = S3Client::factory([
   'key' => $config['s3']['key'],
   'secret' => $config['s3']['secret']
]);

?>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
require 'app/start.php';
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){ 
   $file = $_FILES['file'];

   //File details
   $name = $file['name'];
   $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];

   $extension = explode('.', $name);   
   $extension = strtolower(end($extension));

   //Tmp details
   $key = md5(uniqid());
   $tmp_file_name = "{$key}.{$extension}";
   $tmp_file_path = "files/{$tmp_file_name}";

   //Move the file
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $tmp_file_path); 
   try{
      $s3->putObject([
      'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
      'Key' => "uploads/{$name}",
      'Body' => fopen($tmp_file_path,'rb'),
      'ACL' => 'public-read'       
      ]);
      //remove the file
      unlink($tmp_file_path);
   }catch(S3Exception $e){
         die("There was an error uploading that file.");
   } 
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="file">
       <input type="submit" value="Upload">
     </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error, and what does `$e` say? (btw.: if this is a real `key` and `secret`, you should invalidate it immediately)

Comment: I've suggested an edited version of the code snippet which removes the credentials. Further more, as @ThomasKekeisen mentioned, what is the output of `$e` in the catch block? This would certainly help determine what the error actually is and where to look next.

Comment: Still, you should invalidate them!

Comment: Credentials are accidentally included. I have invalidated them. Thanks